# Raw SQL with FastApi and SqlAlchemy (get all columns)

Tags: sqlalchemy, fastapi, feature-engineering

I have a simple FastApi endpoint that connects to a MySQL database using SqlAlchemy (based of the tutorial: https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/sql-databases/)

I create a session using:

```
engine = create_engine(
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL
)
SessionLocal = sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=False, bind=engine)
```

I create the dependency:

```
def get_db():
   db = SessionLocal()
   try:
      yield db
   finally:
      db.close()
```

In my route I want to execute an arbitrary SQL statement but I am not sure how to handle session, connection, cursor etc. correctly (including closing) which I learned the hard way is super important for correct performance

```
@app.get("/get_data")
def get_data(db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    ???
```

Ultimately the reason for this is that my table contains machine learning features with columns that are undetermined beforehand. If there is a way to define a Base model with "all columns" that would work too, but I couldnt find that either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved this using the https://www.encode.io/databases/ package instead. It handles all connections / sessions etc. under the hood. Simplified snippet:

```
database = databases.Database(DATABASE_URL)
    
@app.get("/read_db")
async def read_db():
    data = await database.fetch_all("SELECT * FROM USER_TABLE")
    return data
```

Comment: is it possible to connect to Microsoft SQL Server using databases? I googled but did not get a definitive answer. I tried using following URL but it did not work. Following works well if I use it directly with SQLAlchemy without databases library.

DATABASE_URL = f"mssql+pyodbc://{settings.DATABASE_USER}:{settings.DATABASE_PASSWORD}@{settings.DATABASE_HOSTNAME}/{settings.DATABASE_NAME}?driver=ODBC+Driver+17+for+SQL+Server"

Answer (score 0):

```
import pymysql, pandas as pd


engine = create_engine('mysql+pymysql://'+uname+':'+password+'@'+server+':'+port+'/'+db) 
con = engine.connect()
df = pd.read_sql('SELECT schema_name FROM information_schema.schemata', con)
return df
```